# How many peers(hyperledger fabric) do we need?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, peer

I thought peer's roll is processing transaction, managing chaincode and ledger.
Already I know there are endoring peer, committing peer, anchor peer, leader peer.

My question is how many peers are needed.
According to fabric docs, when client doing something, it approaches the peer by changing the env.

For example, if there are 1000 clients who access the same channel at the same time, do they need at least 1000 peers? I asked this question because there is only one client in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Many clients can access a single peer. Typically there will be multiple organizations in a Fabric network, with each organization having a few peers for redundancy and load balancing of client requests.